# How to add multiple lines react native web app

Tags: reactjs

How to add multiple lines. I am only getting a field for one line.

```
 <label htmlFor="materialrequired">Material Required</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="materialrequired"
              name="materialrequired"
              placeHolder="Material Required..."
              value={materialrequired || ""}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
     
            />
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear? What do you want to do?

Comment: When i type into this field now it is only one line and it does not allow me to add multiple lines. I want to be able to add more lines.

Comment: As suggested by @MamunurRashid you should use textarea

Answer (score 2):

**Example of creating a multi-line input field:**

```
 <textarea rows="5" cols="60" name="text" placeholder="Enter text"></textarea>
```